# Python email object - updating object properties and resending

Tags: python, email, properties

I have a python email message object

```
mailobject = email.message_from_string(my_valid_email_string)
```

I would like to update some properties of the mailobject (From, To, Return-Path etc) and re-send the email.

I tried multiple ways to update the properties but they are not reflecting in the mailobject

```
mailobject['From'] = 'newvalue'
mailobject.From = 'newvalue'
setattr(mailobject, 'From', 'newvalue')
```

I am new to python. Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

```
original mailobject['From'] = original@email.com
```

I would like to update the mailobject['From'] property to newsender@email.com

Answer (score 0):

The `EmailMessage` object can have duplicate headers. Assigning to a field creates an additional header, it doesn't overwrite the existing header with that name. So if you want to replace a header, you have to delete the old one first.

```
del mailobject['From']
mailobject['From'] = 'newvalue'
```

This is explained in the documentation of [`EmailMessage.__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.__setitem__).